# meteor with lots of database changes

Tags: meteor

I'm getting stock quotes which happen a few times a second.  I'm using meteor to display those quotes.  I don't think meteor can keep up with the database.  What's the best way to keep meteor speedy?

Should I set my query to be non-reactive then somehow manually call when meteor should re-render the templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are updating your db directly (outside of meteor), than meteor will take 10 seconds to reload and recompute the data changes from the database.

If you are updating your db through a DDP connection, than those changes should reflect to your meteor UI almost instantaneously, certainly keeping up with a few updates per second.

Apart from this, your publish function should not expose all fields of a document in bulk. Instead, you should publish just what is necessary to populate your UI.